# Is this technically a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have used this code to add up all numbers up to 1000, which are multiples of 3 or 5. Is this technically a list comprehension approach?

```
print(sum(i for i in range(1,1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5== 0))
```

Comment: it's a generator expression. List comprehensions are inside `[...]`

Comment: Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions/

Comment: " A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. ", per [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 8):

Technically, it's a *generator expression*. A list comprehension always has square brackets and results in a list being created. By contrast, a generator expression can be evaluated element by element without constructing an entire list in memory.

Here's the same code with a list comprehension:

```
print(sum([i for i in range(1,1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5== 0]))
```

This would be a waste of memory as there's no reason to keep all the numbers in memory when computing their sum.

See also:

- [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and clear. So a generator expression is better since it doesn't store the numbers in memory?